# MySQL query to identify record which have only one specific value per month

Tags: mysql

As specified in Title, I need to write a query to get result specific rows(Serial number list) that have only one status that is "expired" status in each month (months would be calculated on end_time). For eg:
My Table is

```
sr_num, start_time, end_time  , renew_date, status
s1    , 15-01-2016, 15-01-2017, 15-01-2016, purchase
s1    , 15-01-2016, 15-01-2017, 15-01-2016, expired
s2    , 15-01-2016, 15-01-2017, 15-01-2016, purchase
s2    , 15-01-2016, 15-01-2017, 15-01-2016, expired
s2    , 20-01-2017, 20-01-2018, 20-01-2017, renew
s3    , 15-01-2016, 15-01-2017, 15-01-2016, purchase
s3    , 15-01-2016, 15-01-2018, 10-01-2017, extends
```

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  sr_number CHAR(20),
   start_time DATE NOT NULL, 
  end_time DATE, 
  renew_date DATE,  
  status CHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO `test` 
VALUES
('s1', '2016-01-15', '2017-01-15', '2016-01-15', 'purchase'),
('s1', '2016-01-15', '2017-01-15', '2016-01-15', 'expired'),
('s2', '2016-01-15', '2017-01-15', '2016-01-15', 'purchase'),
('s2', '2016-01-15', '2017-01-15', '2016-01-15', 'expired'),
('s2', '2017-01-20', '2018-01-20', '2017-01-20', 'renew'),
('s3', '2016-01-15', '2017-01-15', '2016-01-15', 'purchase'),
('s3', '2016-01-15', '2018-01-15', '2017-01-10', 'extends');
```

Conditions:

- "Group by sr_num, end_times"
- status must be only expired on each month

Result should be only one row **s1, 15-01-2016, 15-01-2017, 15-01-2016, expired**

Sample Table: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bHpAAXRAVRJmkxsNDFNcwy/0

Comment: you want a specific row ( and then wchich) or just the list of the year,month  and sr_num??

Comment: *status must be only expired on each month* ??? After `GROUP BY sr_num, end_times` you will have one definite `end_times` value for a group -> only one definite month. What "each" can be?

Comment: @scaisEdge: need list of sr.num, end_time which have only one status (expired) in a particular month.   (for eg: month1 and  status=expired, month2 and status=expired, ... so on. ) If month1 has expired and any other status then ignore it.  I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: @Strawberry: I think you voted for downgrade. added link. Now you can suggest an answer.

Comment: Votes are anonymous, so you can't tell, and shouldn't assume.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @Strawberry: there is no primary key. data pull from NoSQL DB and put it into My SQL DB for Analytics. I observed that I need to write some script to identify these data.

Comment: I don't understand the criteria. Why is s1 valid?